# Why my function to find a word in string in Python doesn't work?

Tags: python, string

I've got a function that takes two string arguments - doc_list and keyword. Function should return list of the index values of original strings if given string contains the keyword. Lower and upper case should not be relevant, commas and periods should not affect the search. For some reason the end list is empty.

```
Example:
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
>>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
>>> [0]
>>> word_search(doc_list, 'car'
>>> [1]
```

Here is my code:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):

    #remove periods and commas and set all to lowercase
    doc_list_lower = [elem.rstrip('.,').lower() for elem in doc_list]
    print(doc_list_lower)

    #make keyword lowercase
    keyword_lower = keyword.lower()

    #split string into list of words
    doc_list_lower_splitted = [elem.split() for elem in doc_list_lower]
    print(doc_list_lower_splitted)

    #return list of indexes of words which matched with keyword
    return [doc_list_lower_splitted.index(elem) for elem in doc_list_lower_splitted if keyword_lower in doc_list_lower_splitted]
    
#check the function
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
```

Result:

```
['the learn python challenge casino', 'they bought a car', 'casinoville']
[['the', 'learn', 'python', 'challenge', 'casino'], ['they', 'bought', 'a', 'car'], ['casinoville']]

[]
```

So the words are cleared, splitted, but the end list is empty. Why is that? I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if keyword_lower in doc_list_lower_splitted` should be `if keyword_lower in elem`; `elem` is a single tokenized document, `doc_list_lower_splitted` is a list of those documents; on that note, you'd want `elem.index(keyword_lower)` as well.

It would be good practice to use different names for different terms and not `elem` everywhere:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    # remove periods and commas and set all to lowercase,
    # split string into list of words
    docs_as_words = [
        doc.rstrip(".,").lower().split() for doc in doc_list
    ]

    # make keyword lowercase
    keyword_lower = keyword.lower()

    # return list of indexes of words which matched with keyword
    return [
        doc.index(keyword_lower)
        for doc in docs_as_words
        if keyword_lower in doc
    ]


doc_list = [
    "The Learn Python Challenge Casino.",
    "They bought a car",
    "Casinoville",
]
print(word_search(doc_list, "casino"))
```

If you want to know which document (by index) contains the word, you'll need to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the last loop:

```
return [
    doc_index
    for doc_index, doc in enumerate(docs_as_words)
    if keyword_lower in doc
]
```

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. So now when i run function for `"casino"` it returns me `[4]` which is true since `"casino"` is 5th in `['the', 'learn', 'python', 'challenge', 'casino']`, but i would like to get `[0]` because in the original list string containing "casino" is 1st. I don't see how to solve that from this place.

Comment: Sure. Added that as an edit.